# Display Custom User Profile Fields in a Block on All of Their Published Pages

Tags: views, users

I have created a role, and have added additional fields to their profile using Profile 2. The fields are part of the location module, and are just basic contact info (address and phone number). They are also able to chose a name, which is used in the url for both their profile and content.

So, when a user creates their account, the url is site.com/their-name. When the user adds content the URL is site.com/their-name/content.

My goal is to display their contact info in a block on all pages they publish. I was able to do this for their profile page with the following view (see attached image). However, I would like this block to appear on all pieces of content that they author.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module.

> Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for
>   different portions of your site. You can think of each context as
>   representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can
>   choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and
>   choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active
>   context.
>
> Think of conditions as a set of rules that are checked during page
>   load to see what context is active. Any reactions that are associated
>   with active contexts are then fired.

Or a simpler solution might be to change your path from "their-name/content" to "user/their-name/content" and only show the block on "user/*/content".

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Scott. The issue is that this block needs to be dynamic, and only show the contact information related to the author of the current node a user visits. So, if I am on user-name-a/content the block would display the contact information for user-name-a. If I am on user-name-b/content the block would display the contact information of user-name-b.

Using contextual filters I am able to achieve this for the user's profile page, but none of the nodes they have published.

Comment: @StephenMartin, I thought you said you had the view and block working?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have not added correct contextual filter in the views. You should add `Content: Nid` contextual filters into your views, which will filter the current node, then add relationship `Content: Author` into your views which will add relationship between current node and its author.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to figure it.

1. Add Content:Author relationship.
2. Add (author) User: Profile relationship.
3. Add contextual filter (author) User: Uid
4. WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE > Provide default value >
   Content ID from URL
5. Select "Also look for a node and use the node author"