# View users contributed content in profile

Tags: users, views

I have users that have profiles using Profile2 module. I created a content type called Projects. A user can add a project, it has fields: title, description, and file. I would like to add a view to the users profile page that lists all of their Projects.

How can I connect the profile to the content author and use a contextual filter to get only that users content when viewing their profile?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** An example to clarify:
If user1 is logged in and views his profile he will see a list of his projects.

If user1 views user2's profile he will see a list of user2's projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the views UI

- Your view must be a view of nodes
- Then, add a relationship with the node's author (the relation is: Content: Author)
- Then, add an other relationship : select **user** and check **profile**. Then you can use the profile node in Contextual filters or Filter criteria. The technic part is that it is a relationship of relationship ;)

Comment: I want to filter on the current profile being viewed, not the current user logged in.

Comment: other help : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85156

Comment: I set up the relationships you suggested, but used Author ID as the contextual filter criteria, and it works nicely. Thanks for the help.